# declare -A on RHEL 5

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

I am using an associative array on my RHEL 6 servers and I just tested the script on a RHEL 5 server and apparently -A is not supported for the declare command on RHEL 5:

```
declare -A var
-bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...
```

Is there any work around for this? Is there any way that I can update only the declare command or only the bash shell to that which RHEL 6 is using?

bash versions are:
rhel5 - bash-3.2-24.el5
rhel6 - bash-4.1.2-9.el6_2.x86_64

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention the Bash versions you're using (hint: `rpm -q bash`).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu added

Comment: Then [Create associative array in bash 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11776468/12892), perhaps?

Comment: You could just compile whatever version of `bash` you need on RHEL 5; it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative arrays were introduced in bash version ***4***.

Since the option ***-A*** is not recognized that means your are using rhel 5 native bash.

You have to compile / build ***bash 4*** from source in order to use associative arrays.